# turn off url rewrites from sql / database

Tags: database, configuration, seo

I have a mage install with url rewrites turned on, but the server does not do rewrites, so I need to turn rewrites off just to get into admin!

I deleted core_url_rewrite, but did not help.

It would not make sense that this was not possible but I have not found reference to such a table online?

Comment: Did you `TRUNCATE core_url_rewrite`, `DELETE FROM core_url_rewrite` or `DROP TABLE core_url_rewrite`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The table is `core_config_data`

Search the path column for `web/seo/use_rewrites`

Change the value column to `0`

Clear your Magento cache so the config table gets re-read.

Comment: These days you don't need sql: `magento config:set "web/seo/use_rewrites" "0"`

Answer (score 1):

You should login in the backend then go to `system->configuration->web->Search Engines Optimization` and set the field `Use Web Server Rewrites` to `No`. Clear the cache and try again.
You might want to rebuild the indexes also. You shouldn't delete all the values from `core_url_rewrite`. The reindex process should add the values again.

Comment: yeah I cant get into admin because rewrites are on.  Guess that wasnt clear enough from the question, but I did ask for sql  option?  And why should I not delete core url rewrite?

Comment: While you can truncate a table, deleting a table will cause Magento to roll over and die. You then end up having to recreate the table to get Magento back as @Mihai points out. And truncating the wrong table will result in Magento being completely borked with the only option being a full database restore.

Comment: You should be able to access the backend  like this: `mysite.com/index.php/admin`

Answer (score 1):

Along with `UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE path = 'web/seo/use_rewrites';`.

**You need to rebuild** the `core_url_rewrite` table, even if it's empty.

```
CREATE TABLE `core_url_rewrite` (
    `url_rewrite_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `product_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `request_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `target_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `is_system` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
    `options` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`url_rewrite_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REQUEST_PATH` (`request_path`,`store_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_PATH` (`id_path`,`is_system`,`store_id`),
    KEY `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE` (`store_id`),
    KEY `IDX_ID_PATH` (`id_path`),
    KEY `IDX_TARGET_PATH` (`target_path`,`store_id`),
    KEY `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT` (`product_id`),
    KEY `IDX_CATEGORY_REWRITE` (`category_id`,`is_system`,`product_id`,`store_id`,`id_path`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CATEGORY` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=283490 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then clear the cache and you may also need to run a reindex in the command line (either reindex all or reindex just the url rewrites).

```
`php shell/indexer.php reindexall`
```