# Upgraded Magento 1.7x to 1.9.1 - categories/products give "Internal Server Error"

Tags: magento-1.9

I have checked compilation is disabled, cache is clear, re-indexed, turned on development mode (I get no errors). Disabled MageWorx SEO, set the theme/package to default.

The site will load for example, the account login/register page/ the home page, and a few other pages. However, the site will not load categories/products.

Guessing this is a rewrite issue? Any ideas why this would happen after an upgrade?

Comment: how about to check your php/apache error log??

Comment: I don't have the necessary access to do so, but the host said that they didn't find anything in there...

Comment: what about search with/ with no results pages? check does your config meet the requirements (as you have no access to hosting - maybe you use shared hosting. Check memory_limit in phpinfo and other params too)

Comment: Sorry, I do have access to the hosting environment but it's not full root access or privileged enough to see the logs myself. That said @zhartaunik I'm not sure I understand your suggestion

Comment: what version of php is running on the server? Is php in safe mode?  Internal server error *must* write an error somewhere, usually into the php error log. Ask your hosting provider if that error log is in fact enabled. Can you get a copy of it to look yourself. This is a php/server issue. Some command/function is causing PHP to hard fail. It could be a required php module is not insyalled, a command that is not supported in current php version, a typo in code.... (as just three possible reasons).

Comment: It can, of course also involve rewrites, and some directive in your .htacess file that is not accepted by apache install. Are you 100% sure the .htaccess file did also upgrade? see this post. disable rewrites, see if that is in fact your issue: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7148/turn-off-url-rewrites-from-sql-database - process of elimination.

Comment: " _host said that they didn't find anything in there..._ " hm, what a dumb hosting support...  do you have any control panel, like cPanel? you can see / configure logs there

Comment: @ProxiBlue PHP version is 5.5.12. PHP is not running is safe mode. I'm also 100% sure the .htaccess file did upgrade.... rewrites were disabled and did not fix the issue either....

Comment: @ADM no, I don't have access to logs. I will request it from them now.

Comment: "rewrites were disabled and did not fix the issue either." - well now you know it is not rewrites ;) You need the logs. The answer will be in there. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you have restricted access to your hosting environment and can't debug the problem properly you can enable developer mode in Magento and also enable error display to give you more indications on what could possibly go wrong.

To do that, open your `index.php` file and make the following changes:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

change to

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE']) || true) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

and

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

change to

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will show you exactly what and where is failing without having to ask your hosting provider for help