# 404 Errors after turning on SEO URL and Secure URLs

Tags: url-rewrite, 404

## Initial Setting:

1. HTTP only
2. SEO Url Turned off

## What was changed:

1. Turned on SEO Url to remove index.php from Url
2. Turned on SSL for Admin and Frontend.

## Issue:

1. 404 Error messages
2. Unable to login to magento admin

## Resolution Attempt:

I tried to reverse the changes that i made, as i was unable to access admin. I did it through database, phpmyadmin.

1. [Restored the Base URL settings in core_config_data](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-do-i-fix-my-base-urls-so-i-can-access-my-magento-site#39753) 
   set: web/secure/base_url to http://www.domain.com/
   web/unsecure/base_url   http://www.domain.com/
2. [Turned off URL Rewrites from database:](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7148/turn-off-url-rewrites-from-sql-database#7167) 
   set value for web/seo/use_rewrites  to "0"
3. Turned off SSL for frontend and admin
   web/secure/use_in_adminhtml     0
   web/secure/use_in_frontend  0
   web/secure/offloader_header SSL_OFFLOADED [this is as originally]
4. Cleared var/cache and var/session removed the contents of both these folders.
5. Reindexded the Catalog urls by running `php -f indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_url`

## Current State:

1. Homepage loads fine.
2. Product URLs do not have index.php in them. causing 404. When i add index.php in the url the product loads fine.
3. Some menu items on homepage have index.php vs some don't.
4. Admin: goes forcefully to https
5. Admin:404 message. the url forces to https.
6. htaccess file remains unchanged, i have checked with a diff of htaccess backup.
7. Htaccess rule for enable rewrite is as "Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine on"

Will appreciate help to have this fixed.